# How can I merge list of three lists in one list using haskell

Tags: haskell

So I have a list like `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` in haskell. How can I make it to `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. Is there any built in function that can do this?

Comment: Do you really want `[[a]]`, not `[a]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`concat`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5B%5Ba%5D%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) will do that!

```
> concat [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do `[1,2] ++ [3,4] ++ [5,6]`